# ADO Oracle Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

Tags: oracle, excel, ado, vba

I have an Excel 2013 VBA macro which needs to call an SQL procedure on an Oracle 12c database. The Oracle procedure is executed (it writes the result into a table) but in Excel I receive the error at `Set rs = cmd.Execute`:

```
Operation is not allowed when the object is closed
```

Below the code:

```
Dim v_userpw As String

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim l_userpw, l_reqid, l_pwhash, l_sighash As New ADODB.Parameter
Dim objErr As ADODB.Error

v_userpw = Cells(7, 1).Value

On Error GoTo err_test
'Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=devdb;User ID=db1;Password=db1;"
cnn.Open
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
Set l_userpw = cmd.CreateParameter("l_userpw", adVarChar, adParamInput, 1024, v_userpw)
cmd.Parameters.Append l_userpw
Set l_reqid = cmd.CreateParameter("l_reqid", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 1024)
cmd.Parameters.Append l_reqid
Set l_pwhash = cmd.CreateParameter("l_pwhash", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 1024)
cmd.Parameters.Append l_pwhash
Set l_sighash = cmd.CreateParameter("l_sighash", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 1024)
cmd.Parameters.Append l_sighash

'cmd.Properties("PLSQLRSet") = True
cmd.CommandText = "{CALL db1.genheader(?, ?, ?, ?)}"
Set rs = cmd.Execute
'cmd.Properties("PLSQLRSet") = False

Cells(8, 1) = rs.Fields("reqid").Value
Cells(9, 1) = rs.Fields("pwhash").Value
Cells(10, 1) = rs.Fields("sighash").Value

cnn.Close

err_test:
MsgBox Error$
For Each objErr In cnn.Errors
    MsgBox objErr.Description
Next
cnn.Errors.Clear
Resume Next
```

The Oracle procedure looks like this:

```
create or replace procedure genheader (
l_userpw in varchar2,
l_reqid out varchar2,
--l_pwhash out raw,
--l_sighash out raw
l_vpwhash out varchar2,
l_vsighash out varchar2
)
```

I need to return the values in the predefined cells.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this is a SQL Server paramater. I am using Oracle as backend.

Answer (score 0):

Try testing the connection state to ensure it is open prior to assigning the connection to the ActiveConnection property of the command object. This can cause unstable behavior. If you don't want to do this in code, you can assign a breakpoint prior to the set line of code and check your locals window for the connection state. Also you need to specify the name of the Oracle Stored Procedure

`cmd.Name = "genheader"`

Cheers,
Boris

Answer (score 0):

Does the procedure actually return a resultset? It looks like it just returns data using output parameters, so you wouldn't get the results from a recordset, you'd get them from the command parameters after the command executes.

```
cmd.Execute

Cells(8, 1) = cmd("l_reqid")
Cells(9, 1) = cmd("l_pwhash")
Cells(10, 1) = cmd("l_sighash")
```